# why filechooser would work for chrome android 4.4 while webview doesn't?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, filechooser

according to Google, filechooser is taken off and no longer working on android 4.4, but why would chrome still working? I have a device that is running android 4.4. My app has a webview, and inside of this webview I have a button which allow user to upload photo. It was working fine until 4.4. my question is that how come Chrome is able to pick up filechooser event but mine is not while both apps(chrome and mine) are running on the same device. what did google do differently? Thanks!

Comment: Chrome is not a WebView based app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug which occurred in KitKat which broke the file chooser for both Chrome  (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278640) and I believe the WebView was affected by the same problem.

WebView only ever supported a file chooser through a private API (i.e. an API which developers shouldn't use or rely on), which was removed in KitKat.

The WebView team are aware of the number of developers wanting this.

As Kinlan has stated, Chrome for Android doesn't use a WebView.

Comment: what i really dont understand is that webview is just like a browser but simpler for me. I know there's a bug for fileChooser in webview, but y chrome is able to trigger the fileChooser event?

Comment: Try and think of the WebView as a different Browser to Chrome. Chrome has support for this feature - the WebView doesn't at the moment.

Comment: that would bring the topic back to what I originally asked. webview and chrome are both browsers. one supports fileChooser while the other doesn't, but they both are running on the same OS. If the api for chrome is diff then wht google gave to the public, y cant we just add a new jar file that takes care of this part?

Comment: that is still very weird to me...both are apps, both are running on the same os and can be on the same device. but one support fileChooser, the other doesn't. what have google done differently?